# How to resolve the issue with reindexing process.Magento

Tags: magento, reindex

I have just re-index the data using custom script and its generate this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))), 0) AS `' at line 1
```

I have tried by making the catalog_product_flat_1 table but still the same issue

Comment: Did you try to clear store full cache, log out, login, reindex all?

Comment: Yeah I did this but no luck at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Could be any of a host of potential reasons.

If you have SSH access, I'd encourage you to reindex via the command line - more robust:

```
cd pathtomagentoinstall/shell
php indexer.php --reindex
```

How many products did you add exactly? Could be a timeout issue, although I'd expect a different error message for this.

EDIT - Also make sure Root category is setcorrectly: Go to System -> Manage Stores and make sure the Root Category is set to the category you're using

Comment: I have just created one product and a category for this product @David Wilkinson

Comment: @Xabby Have you ensured your Root category is set to be correct: Go to System -> Manage Stores and make sure the Root Category is set to the category your using.

Comment: yeah I have "Default Category " as root and its set as default in Manage Stores @David Wilkinson

Comment: 0nly this "Index product prices not index" option is not indexing all the others are done@David Wilkinson

Answer (score 0):

```
        You could try truncating those catalog_product_flat_* tables. Backup your database and then via MySQL console, phpMyAdmin or other MySQL client run the following:

truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_1´;
truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_2´;
truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_3´;



Do this for all catalog_product_flat_* tables. Then re-index the Product flat data index to rebuild / repopulate those tables.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin Panel** - > **System** -> **Configuration** and then click on **Manage Stores** on the left and under the Store Name click on **Main Website Store**.

Choose the Root Category to Default Category. (by Default you may see –Please Select a Category--)

Answer (score -1):

To fix this problem,
Use an FTP or ssh and from your project root folder, go to the location var/locks  and delete all files inside that folder.
Then Log in to the Magento Admin side and try re-indexing.

If this doesn't fix the error, just go to the ssh ,
change the path to YourProjectRootFolder/shell and enter the command
php indexer.php --reindex all

This will fix the problem.

Comment: Actually only this "Index product prices not index" option is not indexing all the others are done@Ans BM